# how to insert new object with variable and value by the end of each object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
            [{ date="4/7/2012",  username="dealcloud",  user_id=304378189},
             { date="4/7/2012",  username="rizwanharun",  user_id=18932327
            },{ date="4/7/2012",  username="aimtoendhunger",  user_id=
            122384145},{ date="4/7/2012",  username="Sindy882",  user_id=
            705160297}}]
```

how can I insert a new object with variable and value by the end of each object.
e.g i want to put location like date,username,user_id,location in each object

cheers for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Your json syntax is wrong.

You can do something like this

```
var jsonObj = [{ "date":"4/7/2012",  "username":"dealcloud",  "user_id":304378189},
             { "date":"4/7/2012",  "username":"rizwanharun",  "user_id":18932327
            },{ "date":"4/7/2012",  "username":"aimtoendhunger",  "user_id":
            122384145},{ "date":"4/7/2012",  "username":"Sindy882",  "user_id":
            705160297}}];
for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length;i++) {
    jsonObj[i].location = "New location";
}
```

Comment: but there is no location keys in the array. wont i have to create those first and after putting the values inside?

Comment: @anjelos even there was no 'location' key initially, javascript allows you to add it later.

Answer (score 1):

remember that Objects doesn't have an order.

```
var ary = [{}, {}, {}];

for (i in ary) {
  ary[i]['new_key'] = 'new val';
}
```

Comment: no when i do console.log it gives me an empty array. as i said from below the location key is not in any of the objects of the array.i have to create it first

Comment: to add a new key inside a JS Object all you have to do is `var a = {}; a['my_new_key'] = 'value';`. If you need to add a new object to an array use `Array#push()` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)